# All [tag:metal-gear-solid] tags to [tag:mgs]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Of our Metal Gear Solid tags, we have [metal-gear-solid](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid), [metal-gear-solid-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-3), [metal-gear-solid-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-4) and more.

But we have [mgs-5-the-phantom-pain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-the-phantom-pain) and [mgs-5-ground-zeroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-ground-zeroes), which makes sense as they are both Metal Gear Solid 5 and we need the subtitles to distinguish between the two, but also [mgs-revengeance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-revengeance) and [mgs-peace-walker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-peace-walker) (and [mgs-5-motherbase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-motherbase) for some reason).

Should the former list of Metal Gear tags be renamed to [mgs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs), [mgs-2-sons-of-liberty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-2-sons-of-liberty), and [mgs-4-guns-of-the-patriots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-4-guns-of-the-patriots) (although the last one exceeds the character limit, I think) to stay consistent?

Comment: Generally we prefer the full name wherever possible and only shorten tags out of necessity to fit the character limit.

Answer (score 3):

**TL:DR;** The tags make perfect sense, at present. Everybody can tell what they are used for, don't try and fix something that is not broken.

Tags allow us to quickly identify a question, and categorise them. We can also use tags to deliberately seek out questions to games we are particularly knowledgeable about, or otherwise keep an eye on a game we have an interest in.

Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on who you ask), tags have a maximum character limit of 25. Because of this, long names are often abbreviated. metal-gear-solid-reveangance has 28 characters. metal-gear-solid-peace-walker has 29, and metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain has a whopping 35.

Since we can not use these names as tags, we abbreviate them. This does not warrant going back and renaming **all** metal gear solid games, as at the end of the day, people know what they mean.

**In the case of Metal Gear Solid, 'MGS' would likely make the tag un-recognisable without rolling over to view the description.**

As for the mother base tag, I believe that just comes down to poor name choice. The user created the tag in context of the companion app released for iOS and Android.